# points within a polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon

Since I am a beginner to `postgis` I am facing problem with finding points within polygons from my table.

This is my table structure

```
   Column    |          Type           |
-------------+-------------------------+
 id          | bigint                  |
 type        | bigint                  |
 geoproperty | geometry(Geometry,4326) |
```

types are 1=point,2=road,3=polygon

I want to get all the points within a specified polygon.

Can somebody help me to get a working query? 
I tried using `St_within` and `st_contains` but failed to get results.

```
select id from test_table g where id = 123 and ST_Within(g.geoproperty,g.geoproperty);
```

Comment: What does "failed to get results" mean? What results do you get? Those two functions are exactly what you need so what is your actual problem?

Comment: I was not able to write proper query , failed to put conditions within st_within function i,e "select id from test_table t where st_within(t.geoproperty,t.geoproperty) and t.id = 123 ;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    id
FROM test_table t1
JOIN test_table t2 ON (ST_Within(t1.geom, t2.geom))
WHERE t1.type = 1
    AND t2.type = 3;
```

You need to use a self-join to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

With your query you select those geometries that are contained within themself which should always be true. Thus you need to add your query-geometry also:

```
select id from test_table t where st_within(t.geoproperty, myQueryGeometry) and t.id = 123;
```

Alternatively use `st_contains`as follows:

```
select id from test_table t where st_contains(myQueryGeometry, t.geoproperty) and t.id = 123
```

Comment: Do I need to pass polygon value in place of myQueryGeometry ?

Comment: Yeap, it is your search-polygon.

Comment: select id from test_table t where st_within(t.geoproperty, (select geoproperty from t where id = 123)); failing by saying  type cast error.

Comment: And what exactly is the error message? What cannot be cast to anything else? Please be a bit more specific on your errors.