# QGIS Select points within ONE polygon in a different layer

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select, select-by-location, select-by-expression

I have a set of points, which are located in the same area where the other, polygon layer is located.

[image]

I would like to have all the points selected, but ONLY within the one polygon belonging to the different layer. I.e. I would lie to have all points selected within the Polygon ID = 1 and so forth.

The following option:
Vector -> Research Tool -> Select by location -> "Are within"
simply doesn't work, because it selects the points falling within the whole polygon layer, which comproses of 7 polygons exactly. I would like to have the selection only within one polygon.

I think, the issue could be an analog to this thread:

[Selecting only polygons that contain another polygon with Select by Location in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412011/selecting-only-polygons-that-contain-another-polygon-with-select-by-location-in)

However, these formulae applies didn't work.

Potentially this option:

[points within a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186055/points-within-a-polygon)

could be doable, but it looks like I have to create some virtual layer first.

I tried also these approaches:

[Intersection between points and polygons in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71250/intersection-between-points-and-polygons-in-qgis)

[QGIS select by location doesn't use selected features only](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251988/qgis-select-by-location-doesnt-use-selected-features-only)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CU1A86JJMIk&ab_channel=OpenSourceOptions

[Selecting features within polygon from another layer using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-qgis)

[QGIS how to select entries not in another layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346908/qgis-how-to-select-entries-not-in-another-layer)

but they didn't work for me.

Is there any way to make this selection just within one polygon of the external layer?

Comment: you tried to do a section by expression using an expression like:
`overlay_within('namePolygonLayer', filter:=id=2)`
expression to write for the point layer.

Comment: Expression is invalid Mate

Comment: I replied, look down

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check "Select features only" option for the polygon layer, you can select the points within the selected polygon.

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you for this swift solution!

Answer (score 10):

Using selection by expression:

```
overlay_within (
LAYER:= 'POLYGON',
filter:= "COD_PROV" = 88)
```

[image]

Comment: Much simpler than mine! I couldn't get this format to work at first, not sure why.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Geometry by expression` tool on the `points` layer, with an expression like this:

```sql
aggregate(
        layer:='points', 
        aggregate:='collect',    -- collect the resulting geometries
        expression:=$geometry, 
        filter:=within(
                    $geometry,   -- the current point geometry
                    geometry(    -- make a geometry from a particular polygon feature
                        get_feature('polygons', 'name', 'polygon 001') -- get the feature where "name" = 'polygon 001', be sure to use single quotes for the field name inside the get_feature() function
                    )
                )
)
```

[image]

---

Or should you wish to select, rather than create a new layer (which is more in line with the question), you can use this expression in `Select by expression` on the points layer:

```sql
array_contains( 
    aggregate(layer:='points', 
              aggregate:='array_agg', 
              expression:=$id, 
              filter:=within(
                         $geometry, 
                         geometry(get_feature('polygons', 'name', 'polygon 001')
                      )
              )
    ), 
    $id
)
```

[image]

It is similar to the first expression, but checks if the feature `id` is in the array of points `within` the polygon in question.