# Comparing two point layers - want to make out point within a certain distance

Tags: qgis, distance, multiple

I just started playing with GIS. A project I came up with, which I personally would find interesting is to find plots which within a certain distance to the high voltage power cables.

I have the point layer for each of these maps, but I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

So what I want to do is check which of the plot points are within a certain distance to the points in the layer with the power cables. I want to check all of the power cable points and there is about 25000 points.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which GIS software are you using? Distances between points and lines are bread-and-butter work for any decent GIS, and you should be able to find a tutorial for your software of choice online. Once you get stuck, this is a good place to ask specific "why do I get this error message?" questions.

Comment: I decided to go with QGIS for economical reasons. I tried googling for it, but ended up asking instead. Didn't find anything related to this. Which keywords would you suggest me looking for?

Comment: Create a buffer for your cable by a set distance and use select by location? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/423913/276

Comment: Since I'm not too familiar with QGIS this is what I came up with in Python - still not getting it right though!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72566874/trying-to-find-all-coordinate-points-within-a-certain-range

Comment: Adding a sample data set could help understanding the question and giving advice.